# Action is not getting called in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, jar

In my struts application action is not getting called instead of that page is getting refreshed . after changing my library jar files. Before changing it worked fine.

Below are the details of my LIB folder after changing

the changes I have made

```
 struts2-core-2.3.16
 struts2-jquery-plugin 3.7.0
 struts2-jquery-grid-plugin 3.7.0 
 xwork-core-2.3.16 
 ognl-3.0.8 
 freemaker 2.3.20
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the following jar in your application: freemarker.jar

Are you new to struts2?.If yes.. follow a proper tutorial. Here is one for ya :)

[Tutorial1](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-struts-2-application-eclipse-example/)

[Tutorial2](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/struts-2-tutorials/)

Comment: My application was working perfect with old versions of above mentioned jar files .. After upgrading those jar file to the above versions my application acting weird like action is getting called instead of that its getting called of previous action ..

Comment: When you download struts2-new version, always download full distribution. It contains all compatible jars(even grid and plugins) and use those only. Jar incompatibility should not be an issue

Comment: Can I have have link if any .. :)

Comment: [Download](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi) See full relases and under that full distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the action attribute of the Struts form tag, by default it's a current action. Missing the action url in the form tag causes the effect of refresh. If you are used the developer mode which turns on by using a Struts configuration constant

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
```

or the corresponding property in the properties file whatever configuration you prefer, generally `struts.xml`. Then you should be notified if the value is incorrect there or Struts can't find an appropriate action configuration.